# .isAfter return even false

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using `momentjs` with [Eonasdan](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) plugin and I'm trying to check if the `end` date is less than the `start` date, for doing this I'm using the method `isAfter`:

```
var start = moment($('#start-datetime').val());
var end = moment($('#end-datetime').val());
console.log((start).isAfter(end));
```

this will return even `false`, the values are so defined:

- start: 07/02/2019 19:58
- end: 31/01/2019 19:58

Comment: Can you check are the values also *valid* using `isValid()`?

Comment: @SamiHult yep, `moment` return `true` to both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a specific format string and locale to `moment` to make sure the string is parsed correctly:

```
moment(..., "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "en");
```

or

```
moment.locale("en");
...
moment(..., "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Demonstration:

```js
moment.locale("en");
$("#test-button").click(function() {
  var start = moment($('#start-datetime').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
  var end = moment($('#end-datetime').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
  console.log((start).isAfter(end));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="start-datetime" type="text" value="07/02/2019 19:58">
<input id="end-datetime" type="text" value="31/01/2019 19:58">
<button id="test-button">Test</button>
```

Comment: for a strange reason I can't get this working, I guess there is a problem witht the plugin or something like

Comment: if I format the date as your code and then call `isValid` the function return `false`

Comment: Please clarify: What version of `moment.js` are you using, and what locale are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 2.18.1 of moment.js and I have no locale plugin

Comment: You're not using a locale plugin, but it may be picking up the locale from the browser. Just to be sure, try specifying a locale (see my updated answer).